# Gravitational wave, Planck length and Schwarzschild radius

Tags: black-holes

I have heard that Schwarzschild radius corresponds to the Planck length when the radius gain the Planck energy.

Is the gravitational wave length (amplitude) equal to the Planck length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you calculate the mass of a black hole with Schwarzschild radius equal to the Planck length then it does indeed come out to be about the Planck mass (it's actually $\tfrac{1}{2}M_p$).

But you are asking about gravity waves, and there is no immediate connection between the wavelength of gravity waves and the Planck units. Gravity waves are like water waves: they can have any wavelength you want. Your question is akin to asking if the wavelength of water waves is the same as the size of water molecules. It's more that the Planck length represents a minimum wavelength that any gravity wave could have, though in practice it's hard to see how you could generate gravity waves of a wavelength anything like as short as this.

Comment: Thanks . then the consequence is Planck length is the minimum wavelength of the gravity wave .

Comment: Water waves *are* gravity waves because the water is held in place by, and its surface is normal to, gravity. Gravitational waves are another thing. Intuitively the gravitational waves emitted by the instantaneous evaporation of a black hole with Planck mass should have wavelength of one or two Planck lengths, because that is the size of the thing they came from.

Comment: The water wave analogy is a very loose one, but I wanted something that would make sense to a non-physicist. The point is that just as water waves can have any wavelength so can gravity waves, though in both cases there is a minimum wavelength possible. Would black hole evaporation produce gravity waves? Wouldn't we expect the evaporation process to be spherically symmetric? In that case there would be no gravity waves.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that [gravity wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_wave) is a term applied to the class of waves including those on the surface of water. I don't think perfect spherical symmetry is possible because the mass-energy needs to decay to a shower particles, or least a couple photons. Momentum is conserved but nothing more.